# Not sure how to do this menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to develop my first website, and I'd like to have something like te menu in the picture where depending of which option I choose a different text (with images) appears. Is there a way I can do this without creating a separate page for each text?

Example 1

[image]

Example 2

[image]

Also, I'm only using html and css, so no javascript involved.

Comment: Could you share your attempts?

Comment: `.radio:checked + .content{display: block}`

Comment: You should provide a code snippet with the html/css involved instead of images.